# Add subtile (srt) file to existing mkv file

Tags: subtitle, mkv, srt

Is it possible to add a subtitle file (srt) to an ***existing*** mkv file?
I can easily embed the srt file in a ***new*** mkv file, but it is quite time-consuming.
If it is not possible just to add a srt file to the mkw container can anyone explain why?
I’m using MKVToolNix ver. 9.5.0
Cheers
/Jonas

Comment: you have to create another file anyway. But if you copy video & audio streams, it's not that slow.

Comment: So there is no way around than to create a new mkv container...have to add subtitles to around 25 2160p movies so it is quite time-consuming to create new mkw's ;-)

Comment: I'm no specialist but I don't think you can "append" srt data to the existing mkv file. Superuser site could help you more (question is off-topic for SO)

Comment: Ok and thanx for answering. What do you mean with the question is off-tropic for SO?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I found an explaining  answer in a superuser group.
*"It cannot just be added at the end. The srt file needs to be splitted into the individual lines and interleaved with the video and audio blocks through the whole file. The clusters and cues need to be adjusted for all tracks, headers need to be added and updated. It is a complicated process."

https://www.matroska.org/technical/diagram/index.html*